# Make enumerate indent stretch

Tags: lists, margins

Some of my enumerate lists cause overfull hboxes. For example.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[left=5cm,right=5cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item  Donec Donec aliquet, tortor sed accumsan bibendum, which  Donec aliquet, tortor sed accumsan bibendum.
\item \textbf{Donec aliquet, tortor sed accumsan bibendum},  Donec aliquet, tortor sed accumsan bibendum.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

> Overfull \hbox (1.82425pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 16--17
>   []\OT1/phv/b/n/12 Donec ali-quet, tor-tor sed ac-cum-san
>   biben-dum\OT1/phv/m/n/ 12 (-20) , Donec

How can I make the label margin a stretchable unit? So for the above example it would reduce the distance from the left margin to the numbers (in this list only, but not throughout the document).

I tried

```
\setlength{\leftmargini}{2em plus 0.05em minus 0.05em}
```

in the preamble but it results in an error (*Missing begin document*).

Comment: LaTeX doesn't know where to hyphenate `Donec`. Propose `Do\-nec` for instance, and everything will be OK. B.t.w., do you really need a horizontal margin of 5cm?

Comment: The text and margins are only to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Yes, but it shows it's only a hyphenation problem. You'll always have hyphenation problems from time to time with a comparatively small text width. For me, a stretchable list margin is nonsense. You can use `\sloppy`.

Comment: It's a little exotic to be sure, but to me I thought, if possible, an enumerated list with numbers slightly closer to the left margin on one page would be less noticeable than a word protruding into the right margin (or extra hyphenation).

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, I don't think these lengths can be stretchable.

Comment: @Bernard: True, that's two different registers between skip and dimen